# FirebaseMessaging generates same token

Tags: android, firebase-cloud-messaging

I'm trying to generate a new messaging token but it seems to generate the same one, over and over again.

I tried both

```
FirebaseMessaging.getInstance().deleteToken().addOnCompleteListener {
  Log.d("Notifications", "Token Deleted!!!")
}
```

and

```
FirebaseInstallations.getInstance().delete().addOnCompleteListener {
  Log.d("Notifications", "Token Deleted!!!")
}
```

Neither seem to trigger the

```
override fun onNewToken(refreshedToken: String) {}
```

of the service. And each time i query for the current token i get the same one.

What am i doing wrong?

Comment: You can check add this line and it will work :-FirebaseMessaging.getInstance().deleteToken().addOnSuccessListener { FirebaseMessaging.getInstance().getToken() }

Answer (score 0):

I am not exactly sure if you can delete the generated token to get a new one. However, as per [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/android/client#sample-register) a token is generated once on app's initial startup.

If you want a new token - simply uninstall the app and install it once again. Then Firebase will generate a new token.

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same issue when trying to log out users.

I would recommend using the depreciated method below:

```
       Thread(Runnable {
            Thread.sleep(1000)

           
            FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().deleteInstanceId()


        }).start()
```

This will not call onNewToken, however, if you now call..

```
  FirebaseMessaging.getInstance().token.addOnCompleteListener { -> task
  // get the result here
  }
```

Result should be a new token